# C# - I can't seem to be able to pass in an array to different methods, one to initialise and one to modify?

Tags: c#

I am creating a Tic-Tac-Toe game and I wanted to have a method which would draw the grid (`DrawGrid`) and a method for the player's move (`PlayerMove`). In `PlayerMove`, I wanted to modify the array which would change one of the boxes' value to an "X" or an "O" (adding the different players later). The values in the boxes should change to an "X" or an "O" but isn't.

Firstly, I put my for loop from `PlayerMove` in the Main method, but realized that wouldn't work so I put it in it's own method, however I kept the array, for the values in the boxes, in the Main method, but that didn't work when I tried to pass in by reference (is the reason why it won't change is because it `arr` still points to the original array and if so, how do I make it so both instances point to the new array?). Then I tried tackling the problem by declaring a field/property outside the Main method and initializing it in another method. Then I passed in arr and changed some values in the array (or just a value) in another method.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe. Player 1 = X and Player 2 = O");

    string[] arr = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" }; //**each char for each square in the grid - defining array**
    int player = 1; //**player is set to 1 in the beginning to allow for error checking (now set to 2 because of iteration - test)**
    string answer; //**user input**
    bool win = false; //**win condition**
    bool error = false; //**validating user input**
    while (win == false) //**loop for each player's turn**
    {
        DrawGrid(ref arr);
        //Console.WriteLine("");
        //Console.WriteLine("|{0}|{1}|{2}|\n|{3}|{4}|{5}|\n|{6}|{7}|{8}|", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5], arr[6], arr[7], arr[8]);
        //**put iterating player turns here**

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Player {0}'s turn. Enter a number slot", player);
        answer = Console.ReadLine();

        if (error == false)
        {
            PlayerMove(ref answer, ref arr); //make player move
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }    
        //DrawGrid(ref arr);
    }
}

//string[] arr;

private static void DrawGrid(ref string[] arr)
{
    //char[] arr = new char[9];
    //string[] arr = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };

    Console.WriteLine("|{0}|{1}|{2}|\n|{3}|{4}|{5}|\n|{6}|{7}|{8}|", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5], arr[6], arr[7], arr[8]);
}

private static void PlayerMove(ref string answer, ref string[] arr) //**make whole new class for this method?**
{
    for (int i = 0; i > 8; i++) //make player move
    {
        if (answer == arr[i])
        {
            arr[i] = "X";
        }
    }
}
```

The comments with `**` I made to understand my code. The other comments are different parts of code I have tried trying to fix my problem.

Comment: This isn't anything close to a Unity `MonoBehaviour` implementation .. it seems like you should go through the [Getting Started Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityBasics.html). You don't use the `Main` in Unity and also no `while` loop per se but rather a [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) with the game logic mainly happening in [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html)

Comment: ...or is this even a Unity question at all? If you aren't using Unity, don't tag your question with Unity.

Comment: Sorry, its not Unity. I got confused with the starter tutorial and thought the tags was just tags I was just interested in to setup my profile or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for loop condition in your PlayerMove method is making it impossible to iterate through.

initial value of i = 0, while condition of i>8 is always false on first itertation, change PlayerMove method to this:

```
private static void PlayerMove(ref string answer, ref string[] arr)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) //make player move
    {
      if (answer == arr[i])
      {
        arr[i] = "X";
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, can't believe I managed to let that slip past

Comment: you can mark this solution as accepted if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

@Rashid's answer is correct. Your for loop condition is wrong. But I would like to add a few other things:

- The passing by ref is totally unnecessary. Only value types need the ref keyword and arrays are not value types. You can always change the contents of the array without the ref keyword, but you cannot make it point to a different array.
- Another thing is the "else-continue"-part. When the execution gets to there, it just goes to the while condition, which it would have done anyway.
- And then there is one of my pet peeves: Never compare a boolean expression to true or false. `If (a==true)` is the same as `if (a)`. `If (a==false)` is the same as `if (!a)`.

The code below works fine:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe. Player 1 = X and Player 2 = O");

    string[] arr = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" }; //each char for each square in the grid - defining array
    int player = 1; //player is set to 1 in the beginning to allow for error checking (now set to 2 because of iteration - test)**
    string answer; //user input**
    bool win = false; //win condition**
    bool error = false; //validating user input**
    while (!win) //loop for each player's turn**
    {
        DrawGrid(arr);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Player {0}'s turn. Enter a number slot", player);
        answer = Console.ReadLine();

        if (!error)
        {
            PlayerMove(answer, arr); //make player move
        }
    }
}

private static void DrawGrid(string[] arr)
{
    Console.WriteLine("|{0}|{1}|{2}|\n|{3}|{4}|{5}|\n|{6}|{7}|{8}|", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5], arr[6], arr[7], arr[8]);
}

private static void PlayerMove(string answer, string[] arr) //make whole new class for this method?**
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) //make player move
    {
        if (answer == arr[i])
        {
            arr[i] = "X";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I managed to let that for loop slip past. And I added the else continue because if there was an error it would skip their turn and go to the next iteration in the while loop. Thanks

Comment: Would it work if I made a field or property outside the main method then I initialised it in DrawGrid and passed the array in through PlayerMove? Thanks

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention there is extra code after that. I wanted to skip this code. Thanks and I'm sorry about the loads of comments

Comment: Yes, a field outside the Main method would work, but it would have to be static since your methods are static. I wouldn't recommend it. Static is for method that don't mingle with an object's state.